# What is the proper approach to convert complete database from utf8mb3 (utf-8) to utf8mb4 with no downtime?

Tags: mysql

Since MySQL 8.0 has depreciated utf8mb3 (and will subsequently completely remove utf8mb3 support in future), what is the proper approach to upgrade/convert complete database (in production) from utf8mb3 (utf-8) to utf8mb4 with no (or minimal) downtime?

**The problem is not converting, I know there exist multiple scripts for this conversion**. My major concern is downtime. Is it possible to achieve this with no downtime?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UTF-8 all the way through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya No it is not a duplicate, I'm not asking how to, I'm asking how to in a production environment without downtime.

Comment: Maybe by converting a slave and then failover.

Comment: Can a utf8mb4 slave replicate from utf8mb3 master?

Comment: Not that I've ever tried - Just guessed. Even if I knew exactly how to do that, I would probably hire a specialist for this task.

Comment: Replication solution...  I don't know about `BINLOG_FORMAT=ROW`, but it sees like `STATEMENT` should not have any trouble.  However, if you don't already have a Slave set up, that would incur downtime.

Comment: Do you have any Slaves now?  Have you set up LVM?  Is the server already running 8.0?  Do you use Triggers now?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming no Slaves, 8.0, no Triggers, and a few other things, I would recommend

```
pt-online-schema-change
```

It will `CREATE TABLE` with the new schema (utf8mb4), then copy the rows from the existing table (utf8 aka utf8mb3), and use Triggers to keep things in sync.  There is a brief lock on the table at the end to finish up and swap tables.

You would do that one table at a time.

Doc: https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/LATEST/pt-online-schema-change.html

Also search around for it; sometimes abbreviated `pt-osc`.

**With a Slave**

Investigate the "failover" options and speed with RDS.  If you can control the failover, then this method *may be* fast and 'simple' and possible.  I assume it is really Master-Slave, not Master-Master?

1. With the Slave, leave it replicating from the Master.  (Potential problem:  RBR may squawk at utf8 replicating to utf8mb4.  This needs investigating.)
2. Do `ALTER TABLE ... CONVERT TO ...` for each table on the Slave.
3. Failover.
4. Depending on what tools RDS has, it *may be* better to rebuild the Slave(s) from the new Master instead of doing `ALTERs` on the new Slave (which is the old Master).

Suggest you spin up some tiny instances with the same Master-Slave topology and version and charsets.  Then try the steps.  It does not need may rows, but it does need `FOREIGN KEYs`, Triggers, etc, in case any of them cause trouble.  (Note how pt-osc has some issues with FKs.)

Comment: We do have a slave, we have RDS Multi-AZ as well. We are on 8.0 with GTID enabled, binlog format row. Not using any trigger as of now

Comment: So according to you we should convert tables one by one?

Comment: Yes, one by one.  I added some tentative instructions for doing the conversion via replication and failover.

Comment: @RajatGoel - And you can generate all the `ALTERs` with a `SELECT ... FROM information_schema.tables ...`

Answer (score 0):

With phpmyadmin,
Select the database, then you'll get a view of all table structures,
Select all tables,then select Operations at the top menu, you'll find a Collation feature, at the end of the page, select the utf8mb4_unicode_ci,then mark the "Change all tables collations" & "Change all tables columns collations" checkboxes, then click go.
The operation takes utmost 7 seconds, and you are done.[image]

Comment: 7 seconds? Is this independent of database size, in production we usually have data size in TBs

Comment: I suggest you have the live database in deployment, try making the modifications before performing the changes on production

Comment: If you are changing the collation, at least go to a newer version:  `utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci`.